# How to spy on method inside a React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this functional component.

**Search.js**

```js
function Search() {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState('sun');

  function handleOnChange(e) {
    if (!e.target.value) {
      return false;
    }
    setTerm(e.target.value);
    return true;
  }

  return <input type="text" onChange={handleOnChange} placeholder="Search" />
}
```

**Search.test.js**

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Search from '.';

describe('when type a valid term', () => {
  it('update the state', () => {
    const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(<Search />;

    // this doesn't work. The handleOnChange method is private. How to deal with this?
    const handlerSpy = jest.spyOn(Search, 'handleOnChange');

    fireEvent.click(getByPlaceholderText(/search/i), { target: { value: 'moon' } });

    expect(handlerSpy).toHaveReturnedWith(true);
  });
});
```

I don't know if I'm trying the wrong approach. I just need to test what happens if the user type an empty term. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You could try putting a breakpoint or a console log inside the inner function

Comment: I'm actually trying to write a test for this function (increase my test coverage), not check if it is performing as expected.

Comment: Does `Search.prototype.handleOnChange = (e) => [your implementation]` not work?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot get access to `handleOnChange`, a better approach would be to check the side-effects, i.e did the state update correctly.

Comment: @deowk you can if you use a `class` component. Check my answer if you're interested

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel That's true but I would not want to be forced to use a class component for testing purposes

Comment: @deowk what's the problem?

Comment: @deowk, since react 18.8 we can use react hooks. React hooks works with functional components, not classes. There is a great advantage by using hooks instead of classes.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel The problem is that if OP wants to use functional components he should not be forced to use class components just for this test case.

Comment: @PabloDarde I understand, I never suggested that you should use a class, in fact I have been advocating against it ;)

Comment: @deowk I agree with you in that case, this why I said that it will be overkill for this solution. However when you have more complex state, class components are more handy to manage and test the state, especially when the state can be updated by children.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel, even if you have more complex components, you should avoid testing detail implementation (by creating classes to turn your test handier). Instead, you should test user behavior. Because of this, I'm not using classes. The question here is: how to get my code tested from the user behavior point of view.

Comment: @PabloDarde Well, unit tests are not meant to test from the user point of view. Testing state, asynchronous update and conditional rendering is not trivial and doing all three at the same time is not a good idea.    React logic can be as complex as backend logic Plus you add the layer of front-end with components rendering. Therefore unit tests are more than welcome

Comment: Well, when testing front end components we should test from the user point of view (I mean, behavior approach instead of detail implementation approach). Testing business logic in the backend (entities, interactors) allows us to change this approach. Maybe [these docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/intro) can help clarify what I mean.  Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please, if you have a better answer left it here. After a search for different approaches, I realized another way to test it.

First, I attached the current state to the value attribute of my search field.

This way, I can check if the attribute value of my search field changes accordingly

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Search from '.';

describe('when type a valid term', () => {
  it('update the state', () => {
    const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(<Search />);
    const inputField = getByPlaceholderText(/search/i);
    fireEvent.change(inputField, { target: { value: 'moon' } });

    expect(inputField).toHaveValue('moon');
  });
});
```

It's possible to write a snapshot test as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is closer to how tests were done in enzyme (test implementation details). I'd recommend checking the documentation of testing-library https://testing-library.com/docs/intro#the-problem

You should be testing as if your final user was interacting with your app. A more appropriate test might be:

```
describe('when no search is present', () => {
  it('displays placeholder text', () => {
    const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(<Search />;
    const searchInput = getByPlaceholderText(/search/i)
    expect(searchInput).toBeInTheDocument()
  });
});
```

testing this way will give you the confidence you need and also code coverage

Comment: You are right @Victor, I need to code in a behavior approach instead of implementation details. However, I didn't understand your suggestion. What is the `handlerSpy` in your code? Thanks to any way

Comment: Sorry about that @PabloDarde, bad copy-paste. I just updated the answer. As you can see, it only checks that the input is in the document with the matcher from https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobeinthedocument

Comment: the person wants to know how to spy though

Answer (score -4):

You struggle to test it because you're testing to many things at the same time.

Here's a solution where I decouple your state from your rendering.
I converted your component to a class component so now you can have access to state and methods using [enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html).

**Note:** your example is very simple and these tests might sound overkill.
But it's a nice example to understand *what* you are testing and *what* tool you can use for each test case.

As a general advice, when you struggle to test something, it's usually because you're testing **too many things**.
And if you're only testing one thing, then maybe you have too many thing at the **same place**.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            term: ''
        }
    }

    handleOnChange(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return false;
        }
        this.setState({term: value});
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        return <SearchInput handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange} />
    }
}

export function SearchInput(props) {
    return <input data-testid="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search"
           onChange={e => props.handleOnChange(e.target.value)} />
}
```

Now we can test each feature independently.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import Search, {SearchInput} from "./App";

describe('Search section', () => {
    describe("Search", () => {
        const searchWrapper = shallow(<Search />);

        it('should update the term on change', () => {
            searchWrapper.instance().handleOnChange("test-input");
            expect(searchWrapper.instance().state.term).toBe("test-input");
        });

        it("should render the search input with handleOnChange", () => {
            const searchInput = searchWrapper.find(SearchInput);
            expect(searchInput.props().handleOnChange).toBe(searchWrapper.instance().handleOnChange);
        });
    });

    describe("Search input", () => {
        it("should call handleOnChange callback when typing", () => {
            const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
            const searchInput = render(<SearchInput handleOnChange={onChangeMock} />);

            userEvent.type(searchInput.getByTestId('search-input'), 'test input');

            expect(onChangeMock).toBeCalledWith('test input');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Since React 18.6, we can use hooks with functional components. We can't use hooks with classes. I don't want to use classes in this project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: hes only testing one thing, that 'handleOnChange' was called.

Comment: @1ak31sha well everyone has its own definition of responsibilities. To me here, there are 3 things being tested, rendering, state management and asynchronous events. As mentioned in my answer, the test I provided is overkill for simple components, but it shows that each responsibility I mentioned can be tested separately

Comment: sure, rendering if being tested but thats only because you must render the component in order to work with it. his test is quite simple and aims to do one thing. i can say the same thing about your test 'should call handleOnChange callback when typing' - it also tests rendering

Comment: @1ak31sha `his test is quite simple and aims to do one thing` - absolutely, that's why I added a note saying that it was overkill. I simply provided a perspective that allow you see what are the different things that you are testing. `[...] it also tests rendering` - It does use the rendering indeed, however it decouples it from the state management. Here we're testing that when the user interacts with the search bar, the callback is called, which is 1 responsibility.

Comment: @1ak31sha again, I'm not absolute how to write tests nor about the definition of a responsibility. It's just that I've noticed many people struggling with testing in React and most of the time, it was because they were trying to test a lot of different concepts at the same time, which is harder and less obvious. That doesn't mean that you want to breakdown everything, but breaking down things can be useful to reduce the complexity of each individual responsibility